# Getting minimum number of occurrence based on another column

Tags: mysql, sql

Problem: How many movies has the minimum number of actors acted in?

Table:

```
title | year | person | role (actor, director, writer, producer)
```

What I've done:

```
SELECT title, count(role) 
FROM movie_table 
where role='actor' 
GROUP BY title 
ORDER by count(role) ASC;
```

What I got:

```
title (007, Dark Knight, Superman, Batman ...) | count(role) (1, 1, 2, 2,...)
```

What I need is a way to to count movies with minium actor role which in this case is 2 (007 and Dark Knight).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really clear what you want but it seems like you are asking for this:

```
SELECT title, count(role) 
FROM movie_table 
where role='actor' 
GROUP BY title 
HAVING count(role) = 1
ORDER by count(role) ASC;
```

Based on your comment, you can use something like this:

```
SELECT title
FROM movie_table 
where role='actor' 
GROUP BY title 
HAVING count(role) = (select min(cnt)
                      from (select count(role) cnt
                            from movie_table
                            group by title) c)
ORDER BY count(role);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b56a/13)

If you then, just want the total, apply the `count()` function to the query:

```
select count(title) Total
from
(
  SELECT title
  FROM movie_table 
  where role='actor' 
  GROUP BY title 
  HAVING count(role) = (select min(cnt)
                        from (select count(role) cnt
                              from movie_table
                              group by title) c)
) x
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b56a/18)

Comment: That didn't solve it. My query is even more close to the solution than yours. I'm not suppose to give it a constant value. I want to get movies with the lowest number of actors. For example, the query could return 5. That is, 5 movies have the lowest number of actors (say they starred only one actor each).

Comment: That is close but is there a way to make it return 2 instead of listing the movies?

Comment: Yes, it worked :) Why did you add x at the end? Also, could you explain the last part with the function count(role)?

Comment: @AKxox the `x` is the alias for the subquery.  the `Having count(role)` allows you to use an aggregate function to filter similar to a `where` clause.  It is filtering the results to only those records that have a role count that is equal to the minimum role count by title